# VBA - Argument Not Optional Error With .Find

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to use .Find to find the cell that contains the name that the user selected, with this I intend to find out information that is in the cell next to it. But when the debugger gets to the line where I am using .Find it comes up with the error "Argument not optional" and it is highlighting "Range". Is the error coming up because I am not correctly using .Find or is it because .Find is not the right thing for the task I am trying to accomplish.

```
    Set NameCell = Range.Find(Name, , Range("OFFSET('People Info'!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA('People Info'!$A:$A)-1,1)"))
```

Comment: Set the range and then offset

Comment: @Raystafarian What do you mean by set the range then offset? do I set the range in a line above or in the argument before the offset?

Comment: Different lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do those separately, like this -

```
Set rngItem = WSTest.Range("A:A").Find(c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
Set rngItem = rngItem.Offset(1,1)
```

First find what you're looking for, and then offset your range. I don't quite understand your goal, so I can't use your example.

Comment: I was using the offset previously to create a list of names for a combobox and I thought I would copy and paste it as the range for the code to look for the name when the user has selected the name, this is not the offset for the information in the cell next to it. do i still need to have it on separate lines

Comment: Yes, you aren't using the `.Find` arguments properly

Comment: oh ok, what would be a better alternative to the offset then?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean. You have a range you found with names and you want to use that range to *find* something?

Comment: Never mind, I just used the Range("A:A") and that worked perfectly.